# Solve $124\, x = 1 \pmod{625}$ for $x$

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

I know the answer is $x = 499 + 625\, z$ where $z$ is an integer, from [this source](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=124x%20%3D%201%20%28mod%20625%29).

I also know that you use the Extended Euclidean algorithm

Comment: Then what do you not know?

Comment: @WinVineeth How to use the Extended Euclidean algorithm to arrive at the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is
\begin{align}
124 \, x &= 1 \pmod {625} \iff \\
124 \, x &= 625 \, q + 1 \quad (q \in \mathbb{Z}) \iff \\
124 \, x - 625 \, q &= 1 \quad (q \in \mathbb{Z}) \iff \\
124 \, x + 625 \, y &= 1 \quad (*)
\end{align}
where $(*)$ is a linear Diophantine equation in integer $x, y$.

The solution algorithm involves the extended Euclidean algorithm.

For the coefficients $a = 124, b = 625$ we get $g = \gcd(a,b) = \gcd(124, 625) = 1$ so we do not have to rescale and $g$ divides $c = 1$, so we have solutions.

The solutions of the homogeneous equation to $(*)$ 
$$
124 \, x + 625 \,y = 0
$$
are 
$$
(x_h, y_h) = (625 \, t, -124 \, t) \quad (t \in \mathbb{Z})
$$

A particular solution of $(*)$ is found using the extended Euclidean algorithm which gives ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=egcd%28124,625%29))
$$
(x_p, y_p) = (-126, 25)
$$
All solutions are found by adding a particular solution to the homogenous solutions:
$$4
(x, y) = (625\, t - 126, -124\, t + 25)
$$
The first component is
$$
x = 625 \,t - 126 = 625 \, (t - 1) + 625 - 126 = 625 \, t' +  499
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
124 x \equiv 1 \bmod 625
\implies 124 x \equiv 1 \bmod 125
\implies -1 x \equiv 1 \bmod 125
\implies x \equiv -1 \bmod 125
$$

Write $x= 125y-1$. Then
$$
0 \equiv
124 x-1 = (125-1)(125y-1)-1 \equiv -125y-125=-125(y+1) \bmod 625
$$
This implies $y \equiv -1 \bmod 5$. Write $y=5z-1$. Then
$$
x = 125y-1 = 125(5z-1)-1 = 625z - 126 = 625(z-1)+499
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Solve the linear Diophantine equation $124x+625m=1$.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, by noticing that $124 = 5^3 - 1$, $625 = 5^4$ and $$(5^3 + 1)(5^3 - 1) = 5^6 - 1 = -1 \pmod{5^4}$$
we get $x = -(5^3 + 1) = -126 = 499 \pmod{625}$.

Answer (score 0):

We wish to solve the congruence $124x \equiv 1 \pmod{625}$, which means we must solve for the multiplicative inverse of $124 \pmod{625}$.

Since $\gcd(124, 625) = 1$, $124$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $625$.  To find the inverse, we use the extended Euclidean algorithm.
\begin{align*}
625 & = 5 \cdot 124 + 5\\
124 & = 24 \cdot 5 + 4\\
5 & = 1 \cdot 4 + 1\\
4 & = 4 \cdot 1
\end{align*}
Now, we work backwards to write $1$ as a linear combination of $124$ and $625$.
\begin{align*}
1 & = 5 - 4\\
  & = 5 - (124 - 24 \cdot 5)\\
  & = 25 \cdot 5 - 124\\
  & = 25(625 - 5 \cdot 124) - 124\\
  & = 25 \cdot 625 - 126 \cdot 124
\end{align*}
Hence, $-126 \cdot 124 \equiv 1 \pmod{625}$.  Thus, $x \equiv 124^{-1} \equiv -126 \equiv 499 \pmod{625}$.